# Multiple plus and minus buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using - and + buttons to change the number of the text box, I am having troubles dealing with different text fields, here is my code:

```js
var unit = 0;
var total;
// if user changes value in field
$('.field').change(function() {
  unit = this.value;
});
$('.add').click(function() {
  unit++;
  var $input = $(this).prevUntil('.sub');
  $input.val(unit);
  unit = unit;
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if (unit > 0) {
    unit--;
    var $input = $(this).nextUntil('.add');
    $input.val(unit);
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=field1>
  field 1
  <button type="button" id="sub" class=sub>-</button>
  <input type="text" id="1" value=0 class=field>
  <button type="button" id="add" class=add>+</button>
</div>
<div id=field2>
  field 2
  <button type="button" id="sub2" class=sub>-</button>
  <input type="text" id="2" value=0 class=field>
  <button type="button" id="add2" class=add>+</button>
</div>
```

And here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jldc/c9ddsy5c/)
You can see in the demo that the values change correctly only if you click buttons on the same field, but if you alternate between fields the values don't change properly.

Comment: What's `this` in `var id = $(this).attr('id');` supposed to refer to? Where is `id` being used?

Comment: Oh, I didn't use that, and i forgot to erase it, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
$('.add').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
});
$('.sub').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
});
```

By using the unit variable you were tying both inputs together. And the plus in `+$(this)` is a shorthand way to take the string value from the input and convert it to a number.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c9ddsy5c/1/)**

Comment: I tried your method for adding and subtracting 0.1
I found out that after some operations the value had the decimal digits like 1.000000000001 and so on. What I can do?

Comment: @Daniele Post a new question with your details and a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

<s>An alternative approach is to use data attributes and have each element store its own value.</s>  Edit: it already stores its own value.  Just access it.

```js
var total;
// if user changes value in field
$('.field').change(function() {
  // maybe update the total here?
}).trigger('change');

$('.add').click(function() {
  var target = $('.field', this.parentNode)[0];
  target.value = +target.value + 1;
});

$('.sub').click(function() {
  var target = $('.field', this.parentNode)[0];
  if (target.value > 0) {
    target.value = +target.value - 1;
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=field1>
  field 1
  <button type="button" id="sub" class=sub>-</button>
  <input type="text" id="1" value=0 class=field>
  <button type="button" id="add" class=add>+</button>
</div>
<div id=field2>
  field 2
  <button type="button" id="sub2" class=sub>-</button>
  <input type="text" id="2" value=0 class=field>
  <button type="button" id="add2" class=add>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same variable to hold the values of your two inputs. One simple option would be to use two variables instead of one:

```
var unit_1 = 0;
$('#add1').click(function() {
   unit_1++;
   var $input = $(this).prev();
   $input.val(unit_1);
});
/* Same idea for sub1 */

var unit_2 = 0;
$('#add2').click(function() {
   unit_2++;
   var $input = $(this).prev();
   $input.val(unit_2);
});
/* Same idea for sub2 */
```

and `unit = unit` just assigns the value of unit to itself, so that's no very useful and you can certainly leave it out.